# Нужно при открытии окна jframe размещать его внизу экрана но над треем

Tags: java, swing, позиционирование, jframe, окно

Мне нужно создать фрейм, чтобы он при запуске размещался справа снизу дисплея но над ТРЕЕМ, проблем с горизонтальным размещением нет, но вот как заставить его понимать указанное выше условие к вертикальному положению? Спасибо если кто поможет.

Comment: определить разрешение эакрана, размер окна, исходя из этого определить координаты верхнего (если не путаю) левого угла окна, с учетом нужного расположения окна на экране и выставить их для фрейма frame.setLocation(new Point( x,y));

Comment: я не понял что значит определить размер окна; я мое окно еще не выводил как бы, я просто хочу узнать высоту окна без панели задач или .. там.. позиционирование может какое-то специальное есть

Answer (score 0):

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
Dimension size = frame.getSize();
Insets scnMax = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(frame.getGraphicsConfiguration());
int taskBarSize = scnMax.bottom;
Point p = new Point();
p.setLocation(screenSize.getWidth() - size.getWidth(), screenSize.getHeight() - size.getHeight() - taskBarSize);
frame.setLocation(p);
```

Comment: Добавьте несколько слов, о том, что это за код и почему он должен помочь автору вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо но не так

Comment: мне надо расположить НАД ТРЕЕМ, а не просто в самом низу

Comment: исправил  - см выше

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Dimension GoodSize(){
    //получение размера основного экрана
    Dimension d=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    //получение какого-то графического Г
    GraphicsEnvironment ge=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

    //получение данных о всех мониторах
    GraphicsDevice[] gds=ge.getScreenDevices();

    //графические настройки первого монитора
    GraphicsConfiguration[] gc=gds[0].getConfigurations();

    //отступы на первом мониторе
    Insets scnMax=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gc[0]);

    //отступ снизу
    int bottom=scnMax.bottom;
    //отступ справа
    int right=scnMax.right;

    d.width-=(size+1+right);//погрешность на единичку
    d.height-=(size+bottom);
    return d;
    //получение данных
    //d.getWidth()
    //d.getHeight()
}
```